# same user with different social network in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, authentication, social-networking

After Googling around I still can't find an appropriate answer to my problem. Let me explain:

I'm creating a WordPress-based site where users will create accounts and login. I allow them to login with Facebook (or Twitter, or G+) and the plugin I'm using (Simple Facebook Connect) creates the user in wp_users table.
Now, I would like to let this user "connect" another social network, Twitter for example. Obviously, if the user logs out and back in with another social network, it creates another profile, and this is understandable.

So, how do I connect another social networks to my existing user? Does Anyone know a plugin which allows this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try these, may offer what you are looking for :

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/rpx/

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/oa-social-login/other_notes/

Hope that helps, if not keep Googling or try Bing!

Comment: Those plugins let you connect with ONE of those social network (i already tried OneAll). I would like to let the user connect with MORE THAN ONE social network AT THE SAME TIME, even if each account has a different email address: for example, to keep social network data in another table connected to my record in wp_users.